# c# : Why is a cast needed from an Enum to an INT when used in a switch statement?, enums are ints

Tags: c#, enums, casting, switch-statement

Can anyone tell me why i need to cast to Int from my enum

```
        switch (Convert.ToInt32(uxView.SelectedValue))
        {
            case (int)ViewBy.Client:
```

If i remove the cast (int) it fails and says i must use a cast.

Here is my enum, and enums are ints.... anybody know about this?

```
    public enum ViewBy
    {
        Client,
        Customer
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C# `enum`s aren't just numbers. Rather, they are numbers associated with the type or  number with a name in a context.

To avoid casts in `case` statements, you can do a cast in `switch`:

```
switch((ViewBy)Convert.ToInt32(uxView.SelectedValue))
```

This, however, has its own problems. For example, this piece of code will write out `7` to the console.

```
enum ViewBy
{
    ChuckNorris = 1,
    JamesBond
}

Console.WriteLine((ViewBy)7);
```

Comment: And it's problems would be what?!?!? do tell

Comment: @jordan.peoples See my update, if you're still interested. Better late then never, huh :)

Answer (score 4):

You should convert your string value to an enum using [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx).

```
ViewBy selected = (ViewBy) Enum.Parse(typeof(ViewBy), uxView.SelectedValue);        
switch (selected)
{
    case ViewBy.Client:
    // etc.
}
```

Also, underlying type for an enum doesn't necessarily need to be Int32.

Answer (score 2):

`Enums` are **NOT** `ints` in the .NET typesystem!
The framework stores them with the aid of discrete integer values - that's a different thing...

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0t5wee3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) :

```
switch ( expression )
      case constant-expression : statement
   [default  : statement]
```

> **The constant-expression in each case
>   label is converted to the type of
>   expression and compared with
>   expression for equality**. Control
>   passes to the statement whose case
>   constant-expression matches the value
>   of expression.

There is no implicit conversion from enum to int, so each of your `case` requires an explicit conversion. Note however that initially switching on an expression of the correct type would make more sense than casting every case (see [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in such case looks kind of lame, having the conversion for a int and all.

Supposing that you'd passed an int, and not a enum, to that method, keep in mind:

1. Are you going to document that well enough so that any time un the future you will be able to fix or enhance the system?
2. Is this enum not used elsewhere? (A pattern on how to deal with that same information is the key for not making juniors mistakes or losing yourself.)

If the answer the both of the two is no, then you should consider keep it for the sake of your own sanity, in a near future.

And btw, is simpler to convert to int and having it to be compared with another int, than a string, per example.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the question "Can anyone tell me why i need to cast to Int from my enum"....

You have to cast to an integer because an Enums values are not integers. Enums have an underlying value that can be stored as an integral type (Default is int).

You can determine the underlying type with

```
Enum.GetUnderlyingType( typeof(ViewBy) );
```

You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a cast to int at all?
If uxView.SelectedValue is a ViewBy enum then simply (ViewBy) uxView.SelectedValue would be enough right?

Comment: It sounds like `SelectedValue` is a `string` here